# Mi video en Html5 no funciona para Chrome de Android

Tags: html, css, html5, google-chrome, video

El típico problema que al momento de ver el  en una pc si funciona pero en móvil no, esto me pasa solo en Chrome de Android, porque al momento de verlo en cualquier otro navegador móvil funciona perfecto.

(1)Algo que he notado es que si entro al sitio > "index.html" y navego a otra página interna como >"contacto.html" y regreso a >"index.html" el video ya carga y se reproduce, pero solo si hago eso.

he probado muchas cosas, pero de primera instancia el video no carga para nada si no hago el método (1), lo de entrar a otra página y regresar a "index.html".

Mi codigo:

```
<video  loop autobuffer autoplay muted playsinline class="html-video"  width="400" style="width: 100%;" id="video">
                        <source src="video/videom55.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        <source src="video/video66.mp4" type="video/mp4">    
                        <source src="video/mobile22/media/mobile22.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        <p>Tu navegador no es compatible con el elemento de video.</p>
                    </video>
```

También intente usar el id de video y poner el js, cambiar el códec etc., etc.

De igual manera no carga si no hago el metodo (1).

De antemano gracias y espero encontrar la solución.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. ¿es posible que [edit] tu pregunta con un video de muestra? Lo digo porque, yo he tenido problemas con el video, pero en Internet Explorer y este problema era por el video en sí mismo y no el código *(tal vez es un tipo de video con algún codec faltante)*. Prueba por ejemplo mirando este [video de muestra de W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4) en tu página desde tu móvil y comprueba si efectivamente es el video. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Has mirado otras preguntas como [Problemas con reproducción de videos mp4 webM en navegadores moviles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/137469/250), [Navegador de dispositivos moviles no reproduce video html5 en formato mp4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/14463/250) o [Autoplay no reproduce el video](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/172292/250)? Parecen problemas similares.

Comment: Gracias compañeros por las respuestas, voy a probar con todo y les comento que sale.